# BaseAdapter context retrieving strange behaviour

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-context

I must be missing something obvious but unable to locate it.

In the below function, If I try to load my Drawable array, I get a null pointer exception saying the getResource is getting called at null pointer, while If i directly pass the drawable and inflate it with the help  of context, it is working fine.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

```
class MyDrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
String[] drawerList;


public MyDrawerAdapter(Context context) {
    drawerList = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Cat_array);
    this.context = context;

}
/*
Drawable[] drawableArr ={MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home),
        MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home)};
*/
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return drawerList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 3 || position == 11) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (position == 4) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.divider, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        row.setEnabled(false);
        row.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        TextView titletext = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.drawer_text);
        ImageView titleImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.drawer_image);
        titletext.setText(drawerList[position]);
        //titleImage.setImageDrawable(drawableArr[position]);
        titleImage.setImageDrawable(MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),R.drawable.home));
    }
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 2) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview_menu, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        row.setEnabled(false);
        row.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem must be in the calling code.

Comment: how to do you call the constructor of MyDrawerAdapter ?

Comment: @DavidJhons  mMyDrawerAdapter = new MyDrawerAdapter(this); in my MainActivity.

Comment: also post the log cat please

Comment: can you show calling code? similer problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490118/android-context-using-this-on-class-that-is-not-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

It is a workaround Which I have implemented but would still like to get the answer if anyone can help.

```
class MyDrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
String[] drawerList;    

public MyDrawerAdapter(Context context) {
    drawerList = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Cat_array);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return drawerList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 3 || position == 11) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (position == 4) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = null;
    int layoutID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + position, "drawable", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.divider, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        row.setEnabled(false);
        row.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        TextView titletext = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.drawer_text);
        ImageView titleImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.drawer_image);
        titletext.setText(drawerList[position]);

        titleImage.setImageDrawable(MrVector.inflate(context.getResources(),layoutID));
    }
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 2) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview_menu, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        row.setEnabled(false);
        row.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    return row;
}
```

}